# How to create multiple bubbles with different colors in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a bubble shooter game, but the bubbles are only colored with the same color. How can I make it possible to randomize the color selection and then get different colors on the bubbles on the canvas?

```
function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(bubble.x, bubble.y, bubble.radius, bubble.wi4, (bubble.wi5 * Math.PI));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = randomColor;
  ctx.fill();
  bubble.x += bubble.dx

  if (bubble.x > innerWidth || bubble.x - boble.radius < 0) {
    bubble.y += 42
    bubble.dx = -bubble.dx
}
```

Comment: Create a bubble class so you can make a bunch of individual bubbles you can give different colors, sizes? But euh, the code shown has `ctx.fillStyle = randomColor;` Why isn't randomColor already working to give you a random color?

Comment: randomColor generates random colors, but the problem is that every bubble has the same random color. I need it to assign a random color to random bubbles, not the same color to every single one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function to generate a hex color

```js
function randomHexColor(){
  let randomHex = '#';
  for(let i = 0 ;i < 6; i++){
    randomHex += [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
  }
  return randomHex;
}
console.log(randomHexColor())
```

And then assign it

`ctx.fillStyle = randomHexColor()`